# How can I get $\mathbf{Cov}(X,Y)$ from those conditions?

Tags: probability, conditional-probability, covariance

\begin{align*}
\mathbf{E}(Y)&=1, \\
\mathbf{Var}(X)&=1, \\
\mathbf{E}(YㅣX)&= 1+X, \\
\mathbf{E}(\mathbf{Var}(YㅣX))&=2.
\end{align*}

From these conditions, I found that $\mathbf{E}(Y)=1$, $\mathbf{E}(X)=0$, $\mathbf{E}(Y^2)=4$ , $\mathbf{E}(X^2)=1$ and I know that $\mathbf{Cov}(X,Y)=\mathbf{E}(XY)-\mathbf{E}(X)\mathbf{E}(Y)$.

How can I get $\mathbf{E}(XY)$ to find $\mathbf{Cov}(X,Y)$?

Thanks for reading.

Comment: For reference, there was no comment about independence but I guess X and Y are correlated so that Cov(X,Y)=/=0

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: @Esen Have you made any progress?

Answer (score 0):

You may use the Law of Total Expectation: $$\mathsf E(XY)~{=\mathsf E(\mathsf E(XY\mid X))\\~\vdots}$$

---

Alternatively, you may use the Law of Total Covariance:$$\mathsf{Cov}(X,Y)=\mathsf{Cov}\big(\mathsf E(X\mid X),\mathsf E(Y\mid X)\big)+\mathsf E\big(\mathsf{Cov}(X,Y\mid X)\big)$$